# Set HOME path globally across multiple tabbed terminals

Tags: bash

How do you change the HOME path so that is set globally?

I like to change my HOME path to the base directory of the current project I am working on for that session, and make heavy use of opening and closing tabs, along with the cd command. Currently, every time I open up a new tab, I have to reset the HOME path to the base directory of the project I am working on. I am looking for a sort of permanent change just for that session while I am working. I can deal with having to change it back to my actual home directory at the end of work sessions if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Started as an interactive shell, as when you open a tab, bash reads `~/.bash_profile`.  So have this rcfile cd into the directly you're focused on.  You might do this with a 'focus' command:

```
#! /bin/bash
# usage: focus             # new bash cd's harmlessly to $HOME
# usage: focus /some/dir   # new bash cd's to /some/dir
echo "cd $1" > ~/.focus_dir
```

, with `. ~/.focus_dir` as the last line of `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: Do I have to add the focus_dir file to every project directory?

Comment: Also, I'm working with a bashrc file, does that make a difference?

Comment: The file is named ~/.focus_dir -- i.e., a'.focus_dir' in your home directory.  Do not place this in ~/.bashrc , but place it in a new ~/.bash_profile .  Please see [Bash Startup Files](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files) and [Tilde Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html#Tilde-Expansion).